# pandas update pandas (0.13.1) to the latest verssion available

Tags: pandas, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade pandas from pandas (0.13.1) to the latest version using pip3 install -U pandas and pip3 install --upgrade pandas both will give me the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
```

my system is: 
ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits
with the following python version :
2.7.6
3.4.3
3.6.3

does anyone have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas`